# How to parse multiple xml file in iPhone using NSxml parser

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, xcode4.2

I have nearly 15 and more xml file inside of one folder if possible to parse all file one by one? I set path like this below if I want to parse multiple files. how can I set path of that folder file?

this code for single file xml parser it's working fine.

```
NSString *playlistfilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CT8OkzhF8qmEYGe2" ofType:@"xml"];  
NSData *playlistfileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:playlistfilePath]; 
NSString *playlistxmlFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:playlistfileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//parsing the XML
PlaylistXmlParser *playlistparser = [[PlaylistXmlParser alloc] init];
[playlistparser parseXMLFile:playlistxmlFile];
```

that all the XML files are having same structure and same element.

Comment: you want to parse two or more xml in one file?

Comment: I guess you will require to create thread for each process so all your parsing processes will run simultaneously in background.

Comment: @PiyushPatel no i want parse multiple i want set that files as a path . thats what i need.

Comment: @mrunal ok but how can i set path for all the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:playlistfileData]autorelease];

PlaylistXmlParser *parser = [[PlaylistXmlParser alloc] initXMLParser:@"xmlname"];
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
```

in PlaylistXmlParser.m file

```
- (PlaylistXmlParser *) initXMLParser:(NSString *)name {

[super init];
xmlname =name;

return self;
```

}

```
now in every methods in PlaylistXmlParser.m file  :

if  ([xmlname isEqualToString:@"xmlname"]) {
    //store  data 
}
else if([xmlname isEqualToString:@"xmlname_1"]){
   //store  data
```

}

Comment: initXMLParser:@"xmlname"]; i want give here for folder file i mean n number of file how can i give.

Comment: just identify for which xml is parse so you can separate in parsing

Comment: you also use like this : initXMLParser:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

Comment: @"xmlname" what is that it is an single file?. agin i have say i want to give here folder file .

Comment: @"xmlname" is just for identify. you can also use anything there

Comment: if i have playlist folder inside of that folder i have lot of xml file how can i implement that folder here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8698/discussion-between-moorthy-and-piyush-patel)

Comment: NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *xml_path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xmlfolder"];
 NSArray *a =[NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"xml" inDirectory:xml_path];
 NSLog(@"%@",a);

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of the NSXMLParser object write the logic of the parsing:-

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
        //check with switch or if else condition which NSXMLParser object is using this delegate.
}
```

As like above all the delegates of NSXMLParser have a parameter as an NSXMLParser object.

Comment: thank you for reply did you under stand my question. this not a answer for this question. i already mention i can able to parse one single file i want to parse multiple file .

Comment: Create multiple objects and give them your appropriate file data after that check using the delegate which object is coming and then write the business logic to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

@moorthy use pathForResourcesType:inDirectory on NSBundle method to get array of paths, Then for every single path inside the array create an instance for the parser class and parse the file.
`[[NSBundle mainbundle]pathForResourcesType:@"xml" inDirectory:"Your directory Path"]` 
This will return an array ...... Hope it helps you